# data encryption on the database level

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have an HR solution, lately we have applied encryption on the salaries on the database.
I have created a 2 C# function, encrypt and decrypt.

I have faced a problem regarding the SQL SUM, MAX, MIN function in the sql commands and procedures that we use, that we use very much.

As a solution, I have created 2 sql clr functions to use them in the database, but the problem is that these 2 clr functions are accessible to any body that have access to the database and can use these functions.

I want to complicate things more for these 2 clr functions, so I am thinking that this function should not work unless the call is coming from my application.
I was thinking to pass something in the application name of the connection string and check inside the clr function.

Things will be more complicated, the only Breach is that, if some one created an application and passed the same connection string.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a job for the security management of the database system:

1. Create a database user for your application (don't use *sa*!).
2. Grant that user the right to execute the CLR functions
3. "Ungrant" all other users the right to execute those functions

Comment: I have thought about this solution, But our customer do not want this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use app_name() to check if the request is from your application

Comment: This is what I was thinking of, but the Breach is that, if some one created an application and passed the same connection string.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN EncryptionByKey](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx). And sure your need grand/revoke the right to Certificate/EncryptionKeys

```
USE YourDB
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101)
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'xxxYOURxSECURExPASSWORDxxx'
GO

ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE EncryptionCert
    WITH SUBJECT = 'EncryptionCert',EXPIRY_DATE = '12/31/2014';
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptionKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptionCert;
GO
-------- Example ----
DECLARE @EncryptionKeyGUID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @EncryptedValue varbinary(256)
DECLARE @DecryptedValue nvarchar(100) = N'Test';

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptionKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptionCert

SET @EncryptionKeyGUID = Key_GUID('EncryptionKey');
SET @EncryptedValue = EncryptByKey(@EncryptionKeyGUID, @DecryptedValue);

SELECT CAST(DecryptByKey(@EncryptedValue) as nvarchar(100))
GO
```